# Autocomplete com texto de div

Tags: javascript

Opa, seguinte, tenho uma lista de links, o que preciso é que ao digitar num textbox esta lista seja filtrada por texto, é possível?

Seria uma especie de autocomplete sem banco de dados.

Comment: Deixa eu ver etendi, você tem digamos uma lista ja pronta em um JSON que contem seus links, ai você precisa de um select com um text input para filtrar a lista de links, sem precisar que a pessoa precise ver a lista toda para encontrar. e isso?

Comment: Quase, no caso não teria json, a consulta seria feita no conteúdo dentro do href, seria um tipo de sugestões, em que no momento da digitação os dados fossem filtrados.

Comment: Show de bola, fico no aguardo. Vlw

Answer (score 0):

A Maneira mais simples de fazer o que você precisa e usando o angular JS, procure aprender um pouco mais sobre esse podoreso framework de javascript.

deixo um exemplo abaixo de como se faz a função que você precisa.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <body>
          <script type="text/javascript">
              var app = angular.module('meuAPP', []);
              app.controller('meuControle', function($scope) {
                  $scope.listaDeSites = [
                    {site:"A",link:""},
                    {site:"AAB",link:""},
                    {site:"BB",link:""},
                    {site:"AVCD",link:""}
                  ];
              });
          </script>
          <div ng-app="meuAPP" ng-controller="meuControle">
              <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="filtro" value="">
              <ul ng-repeat="item in listaDeSites | filter:filtro">
                <li><a href="{{item.link}}">{{item.site}}</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```